# Do I need to normalize my SQLite3 database?

Tags: database, sqlite, database-normalization

I'm currently having an issue where I somewhat understand normalization, but I feel that the way I built my database doesn't require that I normalize it. In simple terms, I'm making an address book keeper with Tkinter Python and SQLite3. I only have one table and it has 9(technically 10) columns.

```
FirstName|LastName|Email|Notes|PhoneNumber|Address|City|State|ZipCode
```

There is an additional column called "ID" which is the rowID that is created automatically and is what I'm using as my "Primary Key."

So with this information in mind, I'm allowing users to add individuals and be able to edit all this information and also be able to delete, etc.

So if someone wants to add a new person, they can do that. If a person moves to a different address, they can change it. New phone number? That can be edited.

This editing of information doesn't create redundancy or duplication in the DB or any other type of "anomaly." However, I would like input from someone else's point of view.

But as much as I look at the situation, I don't see why I'd need to create a new table to normalize the database. This is a very simple database that doesn't seem to require it.

Comment: Not all databases need to be normalized. I think your use case is fine. See [this article](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/).

Comment: @Franklin Yes, thats actually the article I used to try to understand normalization and it's also what I used to come to the conclusion that I might not need to normalize. But I'm still breaking my head over it because I don't know if Im missing something obvious

Comment: Database "normalization" without qualifications doesn't mean a particular thing. What do you mean? If you only "somewhat understand normalization", why do you think you don't "need to create a new table to normalize". You don't tie your situation to your sense of "normalization" so we can't point out a reasoning problem, and otherwise you're just asking for yet another presentation plus a bespoke tutorial. Anyway basics of why normalize & what it is are faqs. PS Time to follow a published academic textbook. And that article's details on normalization is a lot of nonsense. PS Clarify via edits.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that your *table as you describe it is **already sufficiently normalized***.  That's probably why you can't find a practical reason to further normalize it.

But if you discard the idea and do not continually consider the principles of database normalization as you improve or expand upon your database, then you will likely run into problems that database normalization is meant to solve.  Many SQL features require proper normalization and don't work properly or are inapplicable if data is not normalized.

For instance, if you decide that you want each contact to have multiple phone numbers, then you could add `PhoneNumber2` column, or perhaps have two columns `HomePhoneNumber` and `MobilePhoneNumber`.  Then later you might want multiple email addresses, nickname, multiple addresses, etc., etc.

You could start to have duplicate data that would require either manual updates or code that constantly scrubs the database, etc.  Overall the database would become much more flexible if you were to add additional, related tables.  Then, for instance, you could add many different phone numbers without being limited to only 2 columns or having to constantly add and rename columns... which can in turn require significant changes to application code just for adding a new phone-number column.

---

I was going to leave my answer at a high level, since I agree that this topic can get unnecessarily complicated.  But it's worth discussing philipxy's notice of the 3rd Normal Form (3NF) failure... if only to make my answer more concrete and useful.  In the OP's case, the following fields are not completely independent of one another:

```
Address|City|State|ZipCode
```

A ZIP+4 code (00000-0000) would be sufficient to identify an single address.  A 5-digit code would be sufficient to identify a city and state.  So on some level, the inclusion of all fields in a single table has "redundant" data (transitively dependent fields).  To resolve the situation, one could perhaps move the `City` and `State` fields to a separate table and use the ZipCode as a foreign and primary key, thereby further satisfying the 3NF.

Moving the street Address field to another table and linking on ZIP+4 would be ridiculous for one-off addresses, since it would end up producing a one-to-one relationship, essentially nullifying any usefulness of the additional table.  Storing a universal ZIP+4 reference table is likewise ridiculous, since even enterprise-level systems that require street-address verification would utilize a web service for verification in lieu of housing some unwieldy, local, normalized table.

On a practical level, this is rarely done for addresses and zipcodes.  This is not an enterprise-level system and such technicality is usually either deemed unnecessary or altogether ignored.  To be technical, the actual USPS database has zip codes that have multiple acceptable names for places, among other exceptions, so it could get overly complicated fast if trying to apply all normal forms for any possibility.

Could leaving the fields as is allow contradictory and/or redundant data?  Yes.  One could have an incorrect zipcode along side the city, or a ZIP+4 typo that doesn't correspond to the street address.  If necessary, consider implementing an address-verification web service (or even doing it manually online for each address) before worrying about normalization in this case.

The moral of this brief analysis:  Although the OP misunderstood that the table overall already matched multiple normal forms, the OP's intuition was also correct that it is unnecessary (and uncommon) to apply all/certain normal forms.

Comment: I see, this makes a lot of sense and was actually something I was thinking about doing in the future. Allowing for contacts to have more information like you mentioned. In your explanation though, I do see the need of normalization, so I'm glad I'm grasping the idea of what it is and what it's meant to do to a deeper level. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Using common sense a given Address|City|State value always appears with the same ZipCode value so the table violates 3NF with the associated update anomalies. Of course, that doesn't mean that one should bother to decompose it. You haven't said anything that @Mellow can soundly apply to this or any other situation except vague introductory generalities.

Comment: @philipxy  I helped the OP realize the abstract concept could be applied to the OP's stituation, to realize that the table was already normalized--not that normalization was inapplicable.  I've witnessed such misunderstandings a lot with beginning students of database concepts.  They get caught up in thinking that they need to apply every single form!  "Using common sense" is a useless phrase here since with my knowledge (and perhaps your own) a huge percentage of SO questions are ridiculously basic, but database normalization is not "common", rather an abstract concept needing clarification.

Comment: @CPerkins Thank you, I see that. I guess some of confusion about that came from the full-form of a Zip Code as well. I'm used to only using the first 5 digits and was never really aware of what the other 4 digits represented since I never had to actually use them before (In my database, I'm only using the first 5 digits). So you just taught me something extra that I didn't know.

Comment: Did you see either of my comments that got deleted pointing out the problems in your last comment?